# Where is the room that bridges the two universes located?

Tags: fringe, parallel-universe

In the third season finale of *Fringe*, Peter uses the machine to create a bridge between the universes.  I thought this room was located in the base of the Statue of Liberty, as that's where the machine was Over There.  During the events leading up to the finale, the machine Over Here was also moved there, or that's what I thought.  Due to this, I thought the bridged room was in the base of the Statue of Liberty.

Possibly related, some of the promotional images for season 4 include a mysterious shiny round object, which I'd assumed was a hint of what the bridge room looks like from the outside:
[image: Fringe promo image]

Comment: Shiny round object looks like the bean in Chicago. Probably not it though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about where it was in the "real" timeline in Seasons 1-3.

However, due to the events of that season finale, things have shifted around.  I don't recall it being explicitly stated where it was put together in the Season 4 timeline, however, it appears to me to be adjacent to Fringe Division's offices.

**Editing** my answer with information from 4x18:

> The bridge in Season 4's Over There is on Liberty Island.  Since the only difference in its activation seems to be that Peter wasn't there, the two machines in this timeline are almost certainly also in the same location - so both would be at Liberty Island, and Fringe Division's offices are nearby, but not adjacent.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the last episode of S3, where we see Peter exiting the machine, I believe the Bridge Room is adjacent to where we last saw the machine, which was in New York, close to the Statue of Liberty.

In Season 4, it's also implied that Massive Dynamic has provided security and support services, so that's another indication (to me) that it's in NYC.